# Visual studio 2017 docker error running app

Tags: asp.net, docker, visual-studio-2017

I have trying to execute a newly asp net core project from inside visual studio 2017, but always get this error:

> Build path either does not exists, is not accesible, or is not a valid
>   URL

[image]

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Have the same issue. Looks like the app is not being launched from its folder. Rather from ... Common\IDE. But I haven't figured out how to fix it though yet.

Comment: I have a similar issue when trying to publish my docker container to azure. It looks like the path resolution of docker compose is broken. I get Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: build path solutionpath\projectpath\projectpath either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL..

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40763/docker-compose-using-incorrect-path.html

Comment: The answer from @Lars Celie is the correct answer for this - there is a bug report with a fixed version of docker-compose available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my particular case, I was working with Docker for Windows from Edge channel. So I just uninstalled it and installed the latest release from Stable channel https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#download-docker-for-windows. It worked out and the problem went away.

Comment: I got this error on version 17.04.0-ce. I rolled back to version 17.03.1-ce and it went away.

Comment: My god, thankyou, I'm in the same boat as ssmith, running 17.04.0-ce.

Answer (score 3):

I was using Docker for Windows Server 2016 (Edge channel) and got this issue as well. However I was unable to switch to anything.
After finding issue on github here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4710
It was apparently a bug in relative paths.

One of the developers released a new binary for docker-compose.exe(see previous link) for which you can replace manually in your local docker installation. After that it worked for me again.